# Error on killing a cmd process

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to kill a cmd window generated by the following code:

```
@echo off
title servermonitor.bat

** REST OF THE CODE **

goto start
```

And this is the code that I'm using to kill that window:

```
taskkill /f /im cmd.exe /fi "windowtitle eq servermonitor.bat"
```

But it simply don't work and don't return me any error.

What changes should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Double check the window title. If its not returning an error, that means no programs meet you conditions

Comment: It only tells me "no tasks with the specified criteria", but it should be all ok. Does my code work with cmd.exe?

Comment: Try this: `tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe"` If your program is listed there then you need to double check the title.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think I found the problem. Windows 8.1 creates an "Administrator:  " tag before the title! -_-